# itextpdf Redaction :Partly redacted text string is fully removed

Tags: itext

Used itextpdf-5.5.9 and itext-xtra-5.5.9

I am trying to applying redaction on Partly text string but after applied redaction whole string is removed from document.Please find attached screenshot.

[image]

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
PdfCleanUpProcessor cleaner= null;
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(targetPdf));
stamper.setRotateContents(false);
List<PdfCleanUpLocation> cleanUpLocations = new ArrayList<PdfCleanUpLocation>();
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(380, 640, 430, 665);
cleanUpLocations.add(new PdfCleanUpLocation(1, rectangle, BaseColor.BLACK));
cleaner = new PdfCleanUpProcessor(cleanUpLocations, stamper);   
cleaner.cleanUp();
stamper.close();
reader.close();
```

Comment: iText redaction removes all text glyphs even if they are only partially covered by the redaction area, even if only part of their bounding box and not the actual glyph is covered. And as an aside, usually a screenshot does not suffice for resolving an issue, code and PDF are required.

Comment: @mkl, Please find shared linked
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B42NqA5UnXMVMDc4MnE5VmU5YVk/view

Comment: Are you an iText customer and did you also ask this in the iText JIRA?

Comment: @MayankPandey Your example code & file indeed are an example of iText redaction removing everything even covered only partially by the redaction area. What are your expectations, shall only content completely covered be removed? Or only content covered at least by half? Quite likely PdfCleanup can be tweaked accordingly. But please be aware that in that case content which is nearly but not completely covered, can be made visible again which might not be what you desire security-wise...

Comment: @mkl, our expectation is remove only that area which covered by provided coordinate.

Comment: One shouldn't expect that half of a glyph is removed. When text is cut by the redaction area, that text is removed completely. As @mkl indicates, **not removing that text** might be an issue security-wise. I would consider not removing partly covered text as a bug. My interpretation of this question is that you'd like us to introduce a bug. I've also seen this question on our closed ticketing system. This question can't be answered in its current state. More clarification is needed.

Answer (score 1):

The OP clarified in comments that it is indeed his expectation that redaction only removes text which is completely contained in the redaction area; text, though, whose bounding box is even partially outside that area, is expected to remain.

This expectation may be unwise as far as security of redaction is concerned because this way text a casual redactor does not see anymore due to the colored redaction area may still remain in the PDF content available to text extraction or even simple copy&paste.

If in spite of such reservations one still wants to tweak `PdfCleanup` to work like expected by the OP, one essentially merely has to change the `PdfCleanUpRegionFilter` used by the `PdfCleanUpProcessor`: The filter implementation used by default rejects a glyph (and so marks it for removal) if its bounding box intersects the redaction area. To fulfill the OP's expectations, this behavior has to be replaced by a check whether the bounding box is completely contained in the redaction area.

This sounds simple. Unfortunately it is not as simple as it sounds because the clean-up code is not designed for easy replacement of the region filter implementation, many relevant objects or methods are private or at best package protected.

Thus, to achieve the OP's desired behavior I simply copied all of the classes from the `com.itextpdf.text.pdf` package into an own package, therein added a new filter class derived from my copy of `PdfCleanUpRegionFilter` with the different text rejection algorithm mentioned above, and then changed the copy of `PdfCleanUpProcessor` to use this other filter class:

```
/**
 * In contrast to the base class {@link PdfCleanUpRegionFilter}, this filter
 * only rejects text <b>completely</b> inside the redaction zone. The original
 * also rejects text located merely <b>partially</b> inside the redaction zone.
 */
public class StrictPdfCleanUpRegionFilter extends PdfCleanUpRegionFilter
{
    public StrictPdfCleanUpRegionFilter(List<Rectangle> rectangles)
    {
        super(rectangles);
        this.rectangles = rectangles;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the text is COMPLETELY inside render filter region.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean allowText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo) {
        LineSegment ascent = renderInfo.getAscentLine();
        LineSegment descent = renderInfo.getDescentLine();

        Point2D[] glyphRect = new Point2D[] {
                new Point2D.Float(ascent.getStartPoint().get(0), ascent.getStartPoint().get(1)),
                new Point2D.Float(ascent.getEndPoint().get(0), ascent.getEndPoint().get(1)),
                new Point2D.Float(descent.getEndPoint().get(0), descent.getEndPoint().get(1)),
                new Point2D.Float(descent.getStartPoint().get(0), descent.getStartPoint().get(1)),
        };

        for (Rectangle rectangle : rectangles)
        {
            boolean glyphInRectangle = true;
            for (Point2D point2d : glyphRect)
            {
                glyphInRectangle &= rectangle.getLeft() <= point2d.getX();
                glyphInRectangle &= point2d.getX() <= rectangle.getRight();
                glyphInRectangle &= rectangle.getBottom() <= point2d.getY();
                glyphInRectangle &= point2d.getY() <= rectangle.getTop();
            }
            if (glyphInRectangle)
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    List<Rectangle> rectangles;
}
```

*([StrictPdfCleanUpRegionFilter](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/pdfcleanup/StrictPdfCleanUpRegionFilter.java))*

```
public class StrictPdfCleanUpProcessor {
    ...
    private PdfCleanUpRegionFilter createFilter(List<PdfCleanUpLocation> cleanUpLocations) {
        List<Rectangle> regions = new ArrayList<Rectangle>(cleanUpLocations.size());

        for (PdfCleanUpLocation location : cleanUpLocations) {
            regions.add(location.getRegion());
        }

        return new StrictPdfCleanUpRegionFilter(regions);
    }
    ...
}
```

*([StrictPdfCleanUpProcessor](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/pdfcleanup/StrictPdfCleanUpProcessor.java), my copy of `PdfCleanUpProcessor`)*

All classes can be found [here](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/tree/master/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/pdfcleanup).

It can be used just like the original cleanup implementation, one merely has to remember using the copied classes, not the original ones:

```
try (   InputStream resource = getClass().getResourceAsStream("Document.pdf");
        OutputStream result = new FileOutputStream(new File(OUTPUTDIR, "Document-redacted-strict.pdf")) )
{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(resource);
    StrictPdfCleanUpProcessor cleaner= null;
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, result);
    stamper.setRotateContents(false);
    List<mkl.testarea.itext5.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpLocation> cleanUpLocations = new ArrayList<>();
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(380, 640, 430, 665);
    cleanUpLocations.add(new mkl.testarea.itext5.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpLocation(1, rectangle, BaseColor.BLACK));
    cleaner = new StrictPdfCleanUpProcessor(cleanUpLocations, stamper);   
    cleaner.cleanUp();
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

*([RedactText](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/pdfcleanup/RedactText.java#L343) test method `testRedactStrictForMayankPandey`)*

#### The example PDF provided by the OP

[image: Document.pdf]

#### After redaction using the original classes

[image: Document-redacted.pdf]

#### After redaction using the tweaked classes

[image: Document-redacted-strict.pdf]

#### A sanity check with the tweaked classes

[image: Document-redacted-strict-large.pdf]

To be sure the tweaked classes still removed any text at all, I enlarged the redaction area so that "heet", the last characters of "Document Submission Sheet", were completely contained in the redaction area:

```
try (   InputStream resource = getClass().getResourceAsStream("Document.pdf");
        OutputStream result = new FileOutputStream(new File(OUTPUTDIR, "Document-redacted-strict-large.pdf")) )
{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(resource);
    StrictPdfCleanUpProcessor cleaner= null;
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, result);
    stamper.setRotateContents(false);
    List<mkl.testarea.itext5.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpLocation> cleanUpLocations = new ArrayList<>();
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(380, 640, 430, 680);
    cleanUpLocations.add(new mkl.testarea.itext5.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpLocation(1, rectangle, BaseColor.BLACK));
    cleaner = new StrictPdfCleanUpProcessor(cleanUpLocations, stamper);   
    cleaner.cleanUp();
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

*([RedactText](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/pdfcleanup/RedactText.java#L386) test method `testRedactStrictForMayankPandeyLarge`)*

And indeed, copy&paste (and other text extraction methods, too) now only render
"Document Submission S".